# getting parts of a wxpython program to communicate with one another

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

So after writing a bunch of small, personal wxPython apps I've settled on organizing the program into a series of wx.Panel()s like so:

```
class display(wx.Panel):
    <buttons, sliders, etc>
    <sizer>
...
class selector(wx.Panel):
    <buttons and stuff>
    <sizer>
...
```

Then I take these panels and shove them into a single frame, as children to a master panel, at which point I can organize using sizers like so:

```
class mainwindow(wx.Frame):
    master_panel = wx.Panel()
    display = display(master_panel)
    selector = selector(master_panel)

    <sizers and stuff>
```

My problem now is that the two panels need some way to communicate with one another. For example when something (like a filename) is clicked in the selector, the display needs to update accordingly.

The first thing that came to mind was to use the existing events system to create my own custom events and then bind them to handlers within each panel, but I'm not so sure this is the right way to go. Has my decision to subclass Panel() created a problem I wouldn't otherwise be having, or is there a better way to handle this inter-panel communication problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pubsub module.   It gives you pretty much what you described doing yourself: a means to signal using events from one module to another.   It has the advantage that you don't have to set up connections between sender and receiver - the receiver simply declares that it wants to listen to certain types of messages and ... bingo ... it gets them.

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

class display(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,... whatever):
        <buttons, sliders, etc>
        <sizer>
        pub.subscribe("SELECTION_INFO", self.OnSelection)

    def OnSelection(self, info):
        # do stuff with info 

...
class selector(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, ... whatever)
        <buttons and stuff>
        <sizer>

    def OnSomeButtonPressed(self, event):
        pub.SendMessage("SELECTION_INFO", info="some useful info about what was pressed")

...
```

Note that you don't need to get mainwindow involved in this communication between its children.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I actually went and downloaded the module separately, only to notice that it's actually included in wxPython....

Comment: One thing to be aware of: although the interface semantics imply that pubsub is event based, it is not in fact event based, in the sense of wx events.  When you call SendMessage, the flow of excution goes all the way through the subscribers' code before your SendMessage call returns.  FWIW - this caught me by suprise when I discovered it, though most of the time you won't care.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parent that knows about all its child panels, to mediate between them, when a child panel raises an event (either a standard or custom event), the parent binds an event handler that calls methods on the other panels to update them accordingly.

He is some pseudo code added to your pseudo code

```
class display(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(display, self).__init__(*args, **kwarg)
        <buttons, sliders, etc>
        <sizer>

    def do_some_update(self):
        <update>
...
class selector(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(selector, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        <buttons and stuff>
        <sizer>
...


class mainwindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        master_panel = wx.Panel()
        self.display = display(master_panel)
        self.selector = selector(master_panel)

        <sizers and stuff>

        self.selector.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_pressed)

    def on_button_pressed(self, event):
        self.display.do_some_update()
```

Note: This is similar to some previous questions i've answered to

[wx.Python: Passing control between multiple panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505010/wx-python-passing-control-between-multiple-panels/16512073#16512073)

[Passing a tuple between two Panels in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139451/passing-a-tuple-between-two-panels-in-wxpython/17147520#17147520)

Comment: It's would be important to be clear on "who should own this logic"?   In this solution, your design is one where all the logic of "who does what" is owned by the MainWindow - a centralised design, and one where the code in the MainWindow has to change if the implementation of a child changes.   In contrast, the pubsub solution offers a separation of concerns - the child that needs to deal with an event becomes responsible for it, and the mechanism of signalling is decoupled from the implementation of the child guis.